# Ask the detail in the proof of Neyman-Pearson Lemma (Sufficiency Part)

Tags: integration, statistics, statistical-inference

This is Theorem 8.3.12 (Neyman-Pearson Lemma) in George Casella stat inference. Consider testing $H_0: \theta=\theta_0$ versus $H_1: \theta=\theta_1$, where the pdf pr pmf corresponding to $\theta_i$ is $f(\textbf{x}|\theta_i),i=0,1.$, using a test with rejection region R that satisfies

$$x\in R , if f(\textbf{x}|\theta_1)>kf(\textbf{x}|\theta_0)$$ and
$$x\in R^c , if f(\textbf{x}|\theta_1)<kf(\textbf{x}|\theta_0)$$ for some $k \geq 0$, and
$$\alpha=P_{\theta_0}(\textbf{x}\in R).$$

Then (Sufficiency): Any test that satisfies the above is a UMP level $\alpha$ test.

In the proof, I understand $$[\phi(\textbf{x})-\phi'(\textbf{x})]
[f(\textbf{x}|\theta_1)-kf(\textbf{x}|\theta_0)] \ge 0$$. But I don't stand why it still $\ge 0$ after we add an integral. The accepted answer in this question told me this is not the case. [Is it always true that integral of nonnegative function is non negative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3188941/is-it-always-true-that-integral-of-nonnegative-function-is-non-negative)

So I am confused.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confuse the notion of "antiderivative" and "definite integral".

In the question you referenced, the answer implies that ANTIDERIVATIVE can be negative. For example, as you know:

$$\int f(x) = F(x) + C$$

where $C$ can be anything, like a negative number. For example, if we take $C = -4$, then

$$\int 0 dx = C = -4$$

which is correct since we found a FUNCTION s.t. $(-4)' = 0$.

But this is not the same as in Casella-Berger. C&B refers to the DEFINITE integral over all sample points in $x \in \chi$ (check full definition in 8.3.3).

In our case above, if we add limits of integration, and assume $F(x) = C = -4$:

$$\int_{a}^b 0 dx = F(x)|_a^b = (-4)|_a^b = (-4) - (-4) = 0$$

Thus, we have shown the the definite integral and the antiderivative are not the same thing: the former is a **number** (which is zero if the integrand is zero), the latter is a **function** (which can be negative even if the integrand is zero).

Now, as for why it should be greater than zero, we can write the Riemann integral:

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - x_{i-1})f(x_i)$$

where $\{x_0, .., x_n\}$ is a partition of the interval $(a, b)$. Then, if we know that $f(x) \geq 0$, then

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - x_{i-1})f(x_i) \geq \sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - x_{i-1})0 = 0$$

from where

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - x_{i-1})f(x_i) \geq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - x_{i-1})0 = 0$$

So, in Casella & Berger they do the same, but with $f(x | \theta_i)$ over the sample space of $x \in \chi$ so the inequality holds.